# Building hadoop cluster on small nodes

Tags: hadoop

I'm preparing hadoop cluster on four very small virtual servers (2GB RAM, 2Cores each) for a proof of concept.
One server as name node and resource manager and three are data nodes.

Every time I'm running the test job (3,4 GB file with data) - two of data nodes (random ones) are working at maximum capability and one of them is sleeping (monitoring via htop). 
All 3 data nodes are visible in the hadoop GUI.
What am I missing?

Any help will be much appreciated.

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>hadoop-master:8031</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>hadoop-master:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>hadoop-master:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
    <value>hadoop-master:8033</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
    <value>hadoop-master:8088</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/opt/hadoop/hadoop/dfs/data</value>
    <final>true</final>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/opt/hadoop/hadoop/dfs/name</value>
    <final>true</final>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>3</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.permissions</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
    <value>67108864</value>
</property>
```

Comment: how many files are being processed ("3,4 GB" not clear - one file of 3.4 or two of 3 and 4?). Also, what kind/extension?

Comment: First of all it depends on how many tasks processed in your job. Tell how many mappers/reducers do you have per this job? Also give us more another information: what job did you run and how did you run it (hadoop command or smth else)?

Comment: It is one file with json objects (ID and json per line).

Comment: My job has one mapper and reducer. The job gets one by one object from file, does some calculations on data of this object and saves the result. Each object is calculated independently. Job is executed from command line.

Comment: Since your job has 1 mapper and reducer, your job needs just 3 containers (1 for mapper, 1 for reducer and 1 for Application Master). How many vCores are there for each node? Assuming you have 8 vCores (default value of 8, determined by "yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores"), "mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores" set to 1 and "mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores" set to 1, just one node is more than enough to run your job. Since all the three containers could be allotted within a single node. Why do you expect all the 3 nodes to be used?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I'm new in hadoop so maybe I have bad understanding how it works.
What I want to do: 
I have a file with json objects (I can cut this file into smaller files if needed) and an algorithm to calculate some parameters. An algorithm works for each object separatly.
I want to spread this data over hdfs and use nodes to execute an algoritm on data blocks they own (parallely).
Currently - when job is processing, on working nodes there are 2 containers reserved an on a sleeping node is only one. Totaly 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
To increase number of reducers in the file mapred-site.xml I added

```
<property>
    <name>A</name>
    <value>5</value>
</property>
```

After I added additional nodes to cluster, hadoop has increased mappers without any additional change in the configuration. All data nodes are working at maximum capability now.